# Clicking on an URL to launch local application with parameters with Java

Tags: java, url, local, launching-application

I've got a webapp which displays articles and pictures which will be printed in newspapers.

The webapp is just displaying a list of articles with their pictures thumbnails.

Clicking on the articles or thumbnails permits to launch InDesign and edit the article with its pictures (InDesign is a PAO app).

Actually, this works **only with Firefox**. If using Chrome or IE, InDesign application won't be launched. Instead the article will be downloaded and I'll have to double-click on the downloaded file in order to edit it from within InDesign.

Since Firefox v.48, this doesn't work anymore and clicking on the picture just download it.

What I want to build is a Java app that will listen a specific port, waiting for arguments (a local file location). Each time I'll click on a picture, InDesign will be launched directly.

So, in my webapp, each article/picture will have a ***href*** looking like :
http://localhost:6789/myJavaLauncher/localFileLocationToOpenWithInDesign

When clicking on such a link, any article will be open directly in InDesign for editing purpose.

How should I do that ?
-> what is the best way to catch all args passed in the URL (path and file name) and send them to a local Java app that will launch the correct application for the given file ?

Thanx by advance.

Comment: This is not related to programming. It's about your browser settings.

Comment: Hi @Kayaman the problem is not a browser settings one. Firefox, just like Chrome or IE is trying to block any application launching for security purpose.

As my webapp was build upon the fact that it was possible to launch an app by clicking on a link, I'm now blocked.